# Is it acceptable to use object properties that way?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, reactjs

Good day. I'm trying to practise in using react- bootstrap library.
And in it's [tutorial](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#forms/) I saw that ES6 code, that seems a little bit confusing to me.

```
function FieldGroup({ id, label, help, ...props }) {
  return (
    <FormGroup controlId={id}>
      <ControlLabel>{label}</ControlLabel>
      <FormControl {...props} />
      {help && <HelpBlock>{help}</HelpBlock>}
    </FormGroup>
  );
}
```

Is it acceptable to use separate object properties without referencing to an object?

Comment: This be *object destructuring syntax…* https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment Does that help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is perfectly fine. It's called [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).
It's cleaner than this:

```
function FieldGroup(props) {
  return (
    <FormGroup controlId={props.id}>
      <ControlLabel>{props.label}</ControlLabel>
      <FormControl {...props} />
      {help && <HelpBlock>{props.help}</HelpBlock>}
    </FormGroup>
  );
}
```

It also has the advantage of [not just sending all properties](https://facebook.github.io/react/warnings/unknown-prop.html) to `<FormControl />`, but only the ones it needs.